# How to get full detailed usage report of firebase products

Tags: firebase, report, usage-statistics

I would like to bill my customers depending on their usage of firebase. I don't have any customers yet but for me to set minimal pricing I need to know the usage report. We have conducted test on the service and based on that test I wanna estimate the costs to provide it to my client.

I know that there is a table of pricing per product but I wanna bill my customers depending on units of usage within my service and to do so I need to know what is the current usage based on the testing period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in report or API that shows the usage of Firebase products per user of your apps. You will have to build that yourself on top of Firebase.

Total usage reports are available for some Firebase products in their console. E.g. there is a [usage tab for the Realtime Database](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/usage/current-billing/connections), a [usage tab for Cloud Firestore that links to the Cloud console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/firestore/data~2F47173560), and a [usage tab for Hosting](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/hosting/usage/current-billing/storage).

Comment: Thanks Frank.
I appreciate your help

I'm actually looking to know where to find the reports related to the usage on firebase. I'm not intended to show these reports to my clients. However I could not find them.

Comment: Usage reports are only available for some products, and their location varies from product to product. E.g. there is a [usage tab for the Realtime Database](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/usage/current-billing/connections), a [usage tab for Cloud Firestore that links to the Cloud console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/firestore/data~2F47173560), and a [usage tab for Hosting](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/hosting/usage/current-billing/storage).

Comment: Thanks a lot
Your answer really helps and this makes me disappointed bcz i thought i will be able to get full detailed report now only 30 days of usage. Im currently using this one but really afraid that for later on i would need a detailed report if not for me at least for the parent organization incorporated with me. So i appreciate if you could help delivering this note to firebase team (i said that bcz ur profile says u r working there)